# integer to an enumerated type as var?

Tags: delphi

For example I have enum

```
const
  MY_FIRST = 1;
  MY_SECOND = 2;
  MY_THIRD = 3;
type
  TMyEnum = MY_FIRST .. MY_THIRD;
```

and I have function like

```
procedure DoSomething(var _type: TMyEnum);
```

where I should pass `integer` as `TMyEnum`.
By doing

```
var
  some_int_value: integer;
begin

DoSomething(TMyEnum(some_int_value));
```

I have error `[DCC Error] : E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter`. How to solve this?

Comment: At the risk of sounding pedantic, what you have declared isn't actually an enum - it's a few constants and an integer sub-range type. An enum declaration would drop the constants, and replace the existing `TMyEnum` with `TMyEnum = (MY_FIRST, MY_SECOND, MY_THIRD);`, or more idiomatically, `TMyEnum = (meFirst, meSecond, meThird);`.

Comment: Actually it was enum while it was C code. Some things we can't translate from C to Delphi 1x1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `var` parameter requires a real variable, eg:

```
var
  some_int_value: integer;
  my_enum: TMyEnum;
begin
  my_enum := TMyEnum(some_int_value);
  DoSomething(my_enum);
  some_int_value := Ord(my_enum);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `TEnum` is a subrange of `Integer` the compiler only uses the smallest possible type that fits this subrange. In this case it is a `Byte`.

So if `some_int_value` were declared as `Byte` your typecast would succeed. But it actually is declared as `Integer`, so the typecast introduces a temporary `Byte` to store the result of the typecast. The compiler doesn't go that far to write any changes to this temprary Byte back to the source of the typecast. That is why you get the described error.